# I used pagespeed insights so i got this problem. My problem is that “This URL” disabled in my case

Tags: performance, pagespeed, lighthouse, pagespeed-insights

recently i used pagespeed insights so i got this problem. My problem is that “This URL” disabled in my case. Can anyone tell me the solution of this problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kzDQ.png)

I want enable "This URL" option. so how can i solve this problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking on the (i) icon shows the reason:

> There is insufficient real-user data for this URL. Falling back to aggregate data for all user experiences on this origin (https://example.com) instead. [Learn more](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/about#crux)

This real-user data is provided by the [Chrome User Experience Report (CrUX)](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/crux/) and it has various [eligibility criteria](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/crux/methodology/#eligibility) to be included. As your origin is included, it would appear you meet most of that criteria, but the fact URL-level data is not available basically means that the URL you are testing does not get sufficient traffic (from opted-in Chrome users) to qualify to view URL-level data.

So, short of boosting traffic to your site, there is nothing you can do to enable this.